# Can A winform app be switched to a WPF one if MVC architecture is used?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, winforms

If we develop a winform app using an MVC architecture, it should not be too hard to change over to WPF at a later date, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well designed WPF application heavily leverage data-binding. As such, you might consider using classes such as ObservableCollection and others and implement IPropertyNotify when designing your model.

Look up some references to the M-V-VM pattern advocated by Microsoft product groups (e.g., Blend) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Codeplex there is an MVC winform open souce fmwk for developping winforms app
That framework is koossery.MVCwin, located on Codeplex at http://koosserymvcwin.codeplex.com